# dynamic menu does't show online, but it does in netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

this is a piece of the php file

```
 <div id='cssmenu' >

                <?php
                include '/include/functions.php';
               echo BuildMenu(0, Menu());
                ?>
            </div>
```

And these or the two functions in the functions.php

```
    function Menu() {

    $con = getConnection();

    $menu = array(
        'items' => array(),
        'parents' => array()
    );$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id,title,link,parentid FROM dyn_menu ORDER BY id;");
          while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $menu['items'][$items['id']] = $items;

            $menu['parents'][$items['parentid']][] = $items['id'];
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);

    mysqli_close($con);

    return $menu;
}

    function BuildMenu($begin, $menu) {
    $html = "";
    if (isset($menu['parents'][$begin])) {
        $html .= "<ul>\n";
        foreach ($menu['parents'][$begin] as $itemId) {


            if (!isset($menu['parents'][$itemId])) {
                $html .= "<li>\n  <a href='" . $menu['items'][$itemId]['link'] . "'>" . $menu['items'][$itemId]['title'] . "</a>\n</li> \n";
            } 

            if (isset($menu['parents'][$itemId])) {

                $html .= "<li>\n  <a href='" . $menu['items'][$itemId]['link'] . "'>" . $menu['items'][$itemId]['title'] . "</a> \n";
                $html .= BuildMenu($itemId, $menu);
                $html .= "</li> \n";
            } 

        }
        $html .= "</ul> \n";
    }
    return $html;
}
```

The php file doesn't show the generated html that the php script should provide, in a live enviroment, but it does in netbeans.
And i don't know why or how i can resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you make sure that your database connection is correct and the tables populated?

Comment: I use the same function to make a connection for all my queries in the website. They all work perfectly. With the same query i can even fetch the data in the menu-table (dyn_menu). I've tested this. I even tested the existens of the table. But when i use the function MenuBuild, the html code stops where the <?php tag begins.

Comment: What you're saying is interesting. If your file is saved as .html, Netbeans might still parse it as PHP while your server doesn't (AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm / AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm). Anyway I'd look into a difference in server configuration, as you say it's the only difference.

Comment: the file is saved as .php. not as .html.

Comment: just found out that all the other pages do the expected. They generate the html. The index.html and the index.php were together on the server for a few minutes. Don't know if it matters.